# sending mail using Php mailer working in local system , failing in godaddy shared server

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I am trying to send an email using gmail SMTP settings.

I tried in my localhost , it worked .

I downloaded the [phpMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) , in that folder I wrote a PHP file with following contents.

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'mygmail@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'mygmailpassword';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->From = 'myfromadress@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->addAddress('mytoadress.com', 'My name');     // Add a recipient

$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

It worked in local system, But not working in the live server.

I am using Godaddy's Linux shared hosting service.

I live server its throwing the below error.

`Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.`

Comment: [Read the docs on this subject](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment on your question because I don't have enough credentials... So I have to write an answer even though it's not technically an answer... I had similar problems a while ago.  The bug was in my code. The short story is, turn on debug mode and you will have the exact reason why gmail is refusing to connect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm with GoDaddy. You can't use Gmail's SMTP server. You need to use our relay server. Take a look at https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/953/what-is-the-name-of-my-hosting-accounts-relay-server for details. Feel free to follow up with me on Twitter @GoDaddyHelp if you have other questions. ^Nate